# Why does ls say "file exists"?

Tags: cygwin, rsync, ls

In case it matters: I stumbled over this problem when backing up a directory using rsync in a Cygwin environment, and rsync suddenly gave the error message:

rsync: readdir("/cygdrive/d/portable/FirefoxPortable/Data/profile/storage/default/moz-extension+++4c6d0e71-68ce-470e-87aa-8db1a3f6524d^userContextId=4294967295/idb"): File exists (17)

Here, /cygdrive/d/portable/FirefoxPortable is the directory to be saved, and until now, this has worked fine. Suspecting that the real problem is not related to rsync, I did a

```
ls /cygdrive/d/portable/FirefoxPortable/Data/profile/storage/default/moz-extension+++4c6d0e71-68ce-470e-87aa-8db1a3f6524d^userContextId=4294967295/idb
```

and indeed got the error message

```
ls: reading directory '/cygdrive/d/portable/FirefoxPortable/Data/profile/storage/default/moz-extension+++4c6d0e71-68ce-470e-87aa-8db1a3f6524d^userContextId=4294967295/idb': File exists
```

So, idb is a directory (which is true), because `ls` says that it is *reading this direcory*, but why do I get a *File exists* error for a directory?

```
ls -ld /cygdrive/d/portable/FirefoxPortable/Data/profile/storage/default/moz-extension+++4c6d0e71-68ce-470e-87aa-8db1a3f6524d^userContextId=4294967295/idb
```

yields

drwxr-xr-x 1 FISRONA Domain Users 0 May  6  2019 '/cygdrive/d/portable/FirefoxPortable/Data/profile/storage/default/moz-extension+++4c6d0e71-68ce-470e-87aa-8db1a3f6524d^userContextId=4294967295/idb'

and

```
stat /cygdrive/d/portable/FirefoxPortable/Data/profile/storage/default/moz-extension+++4c6d0e71-68ce-470e-87aa-8db1a3f6524d^userContextId=4294967295/idb
```

displayed:

```
File: /cygdrive/d/portable/FirefoxPortable/Data/profile/storage/default/moz-extension+++4c6d0e71-68ce-470e-87aa-8db1a3f6524d^userContextId=4294967295/idb
Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 65536  directory
Device: 5a61dfech/1516363756d   Inode: 12873190524118251466  Links: 1
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (3672028/ FISRONA)   Gid: (1049089/Domain Users)
Access: 2019-05-06 11:32:50.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2019-05-06 11:32:50.190000000 +0200
Change: 2019-05-06 11:32:50.190000000 +0200
Birth: 2019-05-06 11:32:50.190000000 +0200
```

What could be messed up here to cause this behaviour?

BTW, I also checked the parent directory (because sometimes, differences in upper/lower case filenames can result in odd effects under Cygwin, due to the underlying Windows operating system):

```
ls -l /cygdrive/d/portable/FirefoxPortable/Data/profile/storage/default/moz-extension+++4c6d0e71-68ce-470e-87aa-8db1a3f6524d^userContextId=4294967295/

total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 FISRONA Domain Users 0 May  6  2019 idb
```

Comment: Does Windows (e.g. `dir` and Explorer) react in a strange way to this directory as well?

Comment: @DavidMacek : Yes. Explorer says that the directory is corrupt or unreadable.

Comment: Well, there's your problem, I guess. Try checking the file system for errors.

Comment: @DavidMacek : Actually that was it. BTW, I also tried to read the disk on the Mac. It was completely unreadable, and the Mac DiskUtility also was not able to fix the error. I then used the Windows file repair (which took about half an hour), and now everything is back in order.